# Flex - Script timeouts (Error #1502) and WebService component

Tags: apache-flex, flash, web-services, timeout

Hello StackOverflow community,

I am getting a script timeout (error #1502) when I am calling a SharePoint Web Service (CopyIntoItems) when trying to upload large files (greater than 40 MB).

The error does not occur when using the Web Service for smaller files. The large files can be uploaded directly to SharePoint using the web interface therefore it is not a back-end SharePoint issue.

I believe the issue has to do with the logic in the WebService Flex component, however I am not sure how to optimize it and I cannot break down the file into smaller chunks as it needs to be together in order to upload with the SharePoint field information.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Mauricio

Answer (score 1):

Easiest idea - increase timeout for Flex? Does not solve problem itself, of course. See [compiler options](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_14.html) (max-execution-time).

Comment: The problem is it's already maxed out, as it states in the link you posted: "The max-execution-time value specifies the maximum duration, in seconds, that an ActionScript event handler can execute before Flash Player assumes that it is hung, and aborts it. The default value is 60 seconds. You cannot set this value above 60 seconds."